# Post a series of self answered questions

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I'm making a series of manuals about how to use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/), for my own use, in case I forget something, and for my colleagues. I format them in markdown, so I just have to copy and paste to post them.

Is it okey to post a series of self answered questions, sharing these manuals? I know self answered questions are encouraged, but a *series* may be too much.

Comment: Don't worry about it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Self-answered questions are ok in general, but:

- the Stack Exchange format is not the best for "blog"-type posts. Questions should be questions that have answers. If you can imagine more than one solution to each of your manuals, then they might be appropriate for the site.
- Please also note that learning materials are [off-topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, so answers that are in a tutorial format tell me that you might be wandering into an off-topic area.

It [sounds like](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5520/post-a-series-of-self-answered-questions/5522?noredirect=1#comment10751_5522) you have a goal of making a "canonical" Q/A, which is great, but consider it in the context of "frequently-asked questions that center around a common element". An answer would be a thorough explanation of some particular scenario, such that anyone else with that scenario could be directed to that Q/A. A canonical Q/A is useful if several people are having the same problem, so the phrasing of your question is critical. Also keep in mind maintenance of the Q/A across software versions, if those updates change features/functionality -- either specify the versions that the Q/A is valid for, or update it as needed.

Comment: Good points. One of the reasons I wanted to do this is to refer questions about the topic to my answers. I will accept your answer but first I would like to hear other opinions.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I started to reply in a comment, but it got too long to fit. Please see the updated Answer.

Comment: Probably just a wording issue: based on the help and the discussion linked there, _requests_ for learning materials are off-topic, while answers formatted as a step by step guide wouldn't necessarily be. (Intentionally avoiding "tutorial" here because, I agree, "tutorial" sounds like the answer to a question that is too broad for the site).